# Canvas size performance

Tags: html

Im using a canvas that has the browser´s window height and width and I´m using about 20% of the canvas for drawing (this includes doing clearRect to the same 20%).

Does my unused canvas space affect performance?

Comment: Have you seen any measurable effect as it might not matter to your app even if there is a performance difference, ie usual performance issue if it might matter to you you have to measure it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

short answer: YES
the bigger the canvas, the worse the performance - but then again it seems like you have noticed that already and are merely asking for a "good boy"... excuse my sarcasm.

you can save cpu time by changing the internal drawing size below the actual size if the result does not need to look perfectly sharp. besides that - dont use a bigger canvas than actually required.